# Get table data from existing html

Tags: html, html-table

I have a page which has a basic table with 5 columns and several rows. Every column stands for a weekday, every row for a different dish on the menu. I would like to create a page that shows only the menu for today.

I have no write access on this table. (if necessarily I could ask the webmaster to make a few modifications)

it seems logic to me to show everything that has the ID="monday"  but I can't manage to get anything out of it.

This is the existing table:

```
<table cellpadding="4" class="weeklymenu" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr ID="day">
      <th ID="monday" scope="col" width="20%">Monday</th>
      <th ID="tuesday" scope="col" width="20%">Tuesday</th>
      <th ID="wednesday" scope="col" width="20%">Wednesday</th>
      <th ID="thursday" scope="col" width="20%">Thursday</th>
      <th ID="friday" scope="col" width="20%">Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ID="date">
        <td ID="monday" class="date" width="151">08/04/2013</td>
        <td ID="tuesday" class="date" width="179">09/04/2013</td>
        <td ID="wednesday" class="date" width="144">10/04/2013</td>
        <td ID="thursday" class="date" width="141">11/04/2013</td>
        <td ID="friday" class="date" width="152">12/04/2013</td>
    </tr>
      <tr ID="first">
          <td class="piatti" colspan="5" width="779">
              <strong>First dish / Primi</strong>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="first">
          <td ID="monday" height="27" width="151">Riso in bianco</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="27" width="179">Pancetta piacentina</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="27" width="144">Riso in bianco</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="27" width="141">Insalata russa</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="27" width="152">Riso in bianco</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="first">
          <td ID="monday" height="29" width="151">Zuppa d'orzo</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="29" width="179">Minestra di cicerchie</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="29" width="144">Minestra di fagioli adzuki</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="29" width="141">Crema di sedano</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="29" width="148">Passato di legumi cpon crostini</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="first">
          <td ID="monday" height="48" width="151">Gnocchetti sardi broccoli e salsiccia</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="48" width="179">Risotto alla milanese</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="48" width="144">Pennette alla puttanesca</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="48" width="141">Conchiglie tonno e capperi</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="48" width="148">Caserecce zafferano panna e speck</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="second">
        <td class="piatti" colspan="5" height="30" width="779">
            <strong>Second dish / Secondi</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ID="second">
        <td ID="monday" width="151">Controfiletto di puledro</td>
        <td ID="tuesday" width="179">Fesa di tacchino ai ferri</td>
        <td ID="wednesday" width="144">Spezzatino alla goriziana</td>
        <td ID="thursday" width="141">Verzini in umido</td>
        <td ID="friday" width="148">Vitello tonnato</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="second">
          <td ID="monday" height="43" width="151">Cotoletta di tofu con verdure</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="43" width="179">Tortino crecy</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="43" width="144">Mozzarella di bufala</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="43" width="141">Ebly primaverile</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="43" width="148">Falafel con salsa tzatziki</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="second">
          <td ID="monday" height="52" width="151">Prosciutto crudo con melone</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="52" width="179">Persico del Nilo agli asparagi</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="52" width="144">Arrosticini di suino al forno</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="52" width="141">Paillard di vitello alla piastra</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="52" width="148">Trancio di salmone al forno</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="side">
          <td class="piatti" colspan="5" height="28" width="779">
              <strong>Side dishes / Contorni</strong>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="side">
          <td ID="monday" height="28" width="151">Patatine fritte</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="28" width="179">Patate prezzemolate</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="28" width="144">Purè di patate</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="28" width="141">Patate al rosmarino</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="28" width="148">Patate al naturale</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="side">
          <td ID="monday" height="28" width="151">Cavolfiori alla parmigiana</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="28" width="179">Pomodori alla provenzale</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="28" width="144">Piselli alla francese</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="28" width="141">Melanzane alla positana</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="28" width="148">Fagiolini all'olio</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="desert">
          <td class="piatti" colspan="5" height="28" width="779">
              <strong>Dessert / Dolci</strong>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="desert">
          <td ID="monday" height="31" width="151">Crostatine al limone</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" height="31" width="179"> Budino</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" height="31" width="144">Macedonia</td>
          <td ID="thursday" height="31" width="141">Profitterol al cioccolato</td>
          <td ID="friday" height="31" width="148">Fragole</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="desert">
          <td ID="monday" width="151"/>
          <td ID="tuesday" width="179"> </td>
          <td ID="wednesday" width="144"> </td>
          <td ID="thursday" width="141"> </td>
          <td ID="friday" width="152"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ID="ingredients">
          <td ID="monday" class="date" width="151">Ingredients</td>
          <td ID="tuesday" class="date" width="179">Ingredients</td>
          <td ID="wednesday" class="date" width="144">Ingredients</td>
          <td ID="thursday" class="date" width="141">Ingredients</td>
          <td ID="friday" class="date" width="152">Ingredients</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you can never can things with same id

Comment: It's bad practice to use the same CSS id more than once on a page. It would be better to use a CSS class instead (`<td class="monday"`). With duplicate ids, you may not get the behavior you want in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your table to have classes and trimmed down the table to just have two rows and used jquery for manipulation.

This is the html

```
 <table> 
  <tbody>
    <tr ID="day">
      <th class="monday" scope="col" width="20%">Monday</th>
      <th class="tuesday" scope="col" width="20%">Tuesday</th>
      <th class="wednesday" scope="col" width="20%">Wednesday</th>
      <th class="thursday" scope="col" width="20%">Thursday</th>
      <th class="friday" scope="col" width="20%">Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ID="date">
        <td class="monday" class="date" width="151">08/04/2013</td>
        <td class="tuesday" class="date" width="179">09/04/2013</td>
        <td class="wednesday" class="date" width="144">10/04/2013</td>
        <td class="thursday" class="date" width="141">11/04/2013</td>
        <td class="friday" class="date" width="152">12/04/2013</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the JavaScript I used to get the data. You can do whatever you want with it using multiple conditions

```
var data = '';
$('.monday').each( function() {
    data += $(this).html();
});
alert(data);
```

And the link to the fiddle is
http://jsfiddle.net/f2sTT/1/

Comment: thanks, but I think I didn't make myself quite clear. I would need to get the output in a table on another HTML page which runs on my server. so that my server retrieves the data from the other server. (a bit like an rss feed) I presume that your script must be on the same page as where the weekly menu is.
Is it possible to have this script on another page with reference to an outside source? am I wrong to assume that this is possible?


[code]
var data = '';
$('.monday').each( function() {
    data += $www.blabla.com/page1.html();
});
alert(data);
[/code]

Comment: @user2245429 can't you download the data from the external source if you can't get it part by part and then attach that table in your page and manipulate it?

Comment: Hmm  that page is updated weekly and I would like my page to get the data automatically every day. without having to modify it (ever)...

vik

Comment: @user2245429 can you just make a post to that particular website whenever you page loads everytime?